# In itunes when using ipod autofill can you tell it to not use unchecked songs

Tags: itunes

In iTunes when using ipod autofill can you tell it to not use unchecked songs.
It's just a tad annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `Only Sync Checked Items`:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I saw that, but in that case the auto-fill option disappears. I guess it will have to do